# Converting Decimal to Hexadecimal with restrictions

Tags: hex, decimal

I've got a question to which I need someone to help me verify to see if my answer is correct or not.

Showing all steps involved, convert the unsigned decimal number 28.2 to:
Hexadecimal, using 1 digit for the integer part and 2 for the fractional part.

I come up with the answer C1.33, but since I am only allowed 1 digit for the integer part I would assume I would remove the 1?

Answer (score 0):

> Hex, or hexadecimal, is a number system of base 16.
> hex digits are
>   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 A, B, C, D, E, F

```
decimal hex
C1      28
C       12
1       1
```

For `28` is `C1` in hex, you cannot represent it with either `c` or `1`

Please refer: [link](http://www.schoolelectronic.com/2013/09/convert-decimal-fraction-to-hexadecimal.html)

Comment: so what would the answer be ?

Comment: You cannot represent any decimal number with hex value of 1 digit

Comment: Till 16 you can after that any number is more than 1 digit